# Do I have to implement all abstract methods in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, pycharm

I'm adapting the [text adventure game tutorial](http://letstalkdata.com/2014/08/how-to-write-a-text-adventure-in-python/), [github](https://github.com/phillipjohnson/text-adventure-tut/), to fit python 2.7. I'm using the PyCharm 4.5.4 community edition for my IDE. When I don't override a parent method it gives me an error:

> Class WolfRoom must implement all abstract methods

At first to get rid of this error I defined the missing method `def modify_player(self, the_player):` as `pass` but I quickly realized I was overriding the method with nothing which isn't what I wanted. Now if I just remove the method from the WolfRoom class I get an IDE error, as seen above, but it appears to work just fine when I run my game. Should I leave this method out or define it and use `super()`?

Here are some code snippets:

```
class MapTile(object):
    """The base class for all Map Tiles"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Creates a new tile.
        Attributes:
            :param x: The x coordinate of the tile.
            :param y: The y coordinate of the tile.
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def intro_text(self):
        """Information to be displayed when the player moves into this tile."""
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        """Process actions that change the state of the player."""
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def adjacent_moves(self):
        """Returns all move actions for adjacent tiles."""
        moves = []
        if world.tile_exists(self.x + 1, self.y):
            moves.append(actions.MoveEast())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x - 1, self.y):
            moves.append(actions.MoveWest())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y - 1):
            moves.append(actions.MoveNorth())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y + 1):
            moves.append(actions.MoveSouth())
        return moves

    def available_actions(self):
        """Returns all of the available actions in this room"""
        moves = self.adjacent_moves()
        moves.append(actions.ViewInventory())
        return moves
```

...

```
class EnemyRoom(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y, enemy):
        self.enemy = enemy
        super(EnemyRoom, self).__init__(x, y)

    def intro_text(self):
        pass

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            the_player.hp = the_player.hp - self.enemy.damage
            print("Enemy does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".format(self.enemy.damage, the_player.hp))

    def available_actions(self):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            return [actions.Flee(tile=self), actions.Attack(enemy=self.enemy)]
        else:
            return self.adjacent_moves()
```

...

```
class WolfRoom(EnemyRoom):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(WolfRoom, self).__init__(x, y, enemies.Wolf())

    def intro_text(self):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            return """
            A grey wolf blocks your path. His lips curl to expose canines as white as
            the nights sky. He crouches and prepares to lunge.
            """
        else:
            return"""
            The corpse of a grey wolf lays rotting on the ground.
            """
```

Comment: Python doesn't actually have a concept of "abstract"... unless the libraries you are using enforce method overrides by raising errors or something.

Comment: @zstewart Python does have abstract classes and methods, which are enforced by erroring if you try to instantiate a child class without overriding all abstract methods.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee *If* you use the `ABCMeta` metaclass, which falls under the "libraries you are using" referred to by zstewart. The language itself has no concept of an abstract class.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee I see. I've literally never used metaclasses before, and also had completely forgotten about the existence of the `abc` library. *Technically* my original comment was correct, but also irrelevant since the OP is obviously using such libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply raising `NotImplementedError` from a method doesn't *quite* make it an abstract method. You can still instantiate a class that doesn't override all its inherited pseudo-abstract methods, you just can't *call* the methods. (Or rather, you can even call them, if you catch the `NotImplementedError` in a `try` statement.)

You can use `abc.ABCMeta` to make a class truly abstract; the metaclass machinery prevents you from even instantiating a class with an un-overriden abstract method.

```
import abc
class MapTile(object):
    """The base class for all Map Tiles"""

    __metadata__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Creates a new tile.
        Attributes:
            :param x: The x coordinate of the tile.
            :param y: The y coordinate of the tile.
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def intro_text(self):
        """Information to be displayed when the player moves into this tile."""
        pass

    # etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! But If I wanted to keep this version sudo-abstract, just because I'm still learning, could I do this and it would be 'proper'?

  class WolfRoom(EnemyRoom):
      ...
      def modify_player(self, the_player):
          super(WolfRoom, self).modify_player(the_player)

Comment: @TM Here, you *do* need to override all methods decorated with `abc.abstractmethod` if you want to instantiate the class. (You can, of course, choose not to if you just want a derived abstract class, whose children or descendents may final override any remaining abstract methods.)

Comment: Can you think of why the IDE would give me "...must implement..." for the modify_player() method but not for the available_actions() method? What makes this different?

Comment: The IDE is doing some static analysis of your code. It sees that `modify_player` will raise a `NotImplementedError`, but `available_actions)` does not.

Comment: @chepner, thank you! Not understanding that was driving me nuts. I think you just helped me understand this inheritance stuff.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is actually due to the PyCharm inspector making an error, or at least a dubious decision regarding PEP 8 style, when looking to see if there are any non-implemented methods which will raise a NotImplementedError.  Consider this simpler example which is very similar:

```
class Base(object):
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def bar(self):
        return 0

class Child(Base):
    def foo(self):
        return 0

class GrandChild(Child):
    def bar(self):
        return 1

my_grand_child = GrandChild()
print my_grand_child.foo()
```

The above code successfully prints a 0 to the output, because when Python can't find the implementation of foo() in GrandChild it looks up the inheritance chain and finds it in Child.  However, for some reason the PyCharm inspector expects all classes which raise NotImplementedError to be implemented in ALL levels of the inheritance chain.

If you were to follow this style in programs with large inheritance structures, you would find yourself being extremely verbose by implementing methods and making calls to super all throughout the chain, when it simply isn't required.  Personally, I just ignore the error, and think that PyCharm should be updated to not show it if it finds the method implemented in any superclass of the class it is inspecting.

Comment: See bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16776
Marked as fixed in 5.0.x.  I have 5.0.1 and it is still an issue, so I'm guessing this fix is coming soon.

Comment: The issue is now marked as fixed for 5.0.2, I have a lot of these false positives so eagerly awaiting the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to implement all abstract methods in Python to instantiate them as objects (the ones marked with `@abstractmethod`, etc). How you implement these, however, are completely up to you. If you're not going to be instantiating, you don't need to override all of them.

For example:

```
class Animal(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def eat(thing):
        pass

class Slug(Animal):
    def eat(thing):
        pass
```

What this means is that every instantiatable `Animal` must be able to eat, but `Slugs` do nothing when they eat.

Comment: Thank you. I recently read, https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/ which was very helpful. Still trying to wrap my head around it all.